# how to add extra list in list view.builder in flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to add an extra list that shows the total number of entries in `ListView.builder()`.

My code is below, but it is not working as index not possible to compare to length.

```
return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Exp Entries'),),
      body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: noteprovider.expenseentries.length,
          itemBuilder: (context,index){

            if(index==noteprovider.expenseentries.length)
              return Text(noteprovider.expense_total.toString());
            else
             return Text(noteprovider.expenseentries[index].title);

          }),
    );
```

Comment: do you mean extra Item on ListView?

Comment: yes....but that extra item shows the total

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must add +1 to length on itemCount :

```
return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Exp Entries'),),
      body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: noteprovider.expenseentries.length + 1,
          itemBuilder: (context,index){

            if(index==noteprovider.expenseentries.length)
              return Text(noteprovider.expense_total.toString());
            else
             return Text(noteprovider.expenseentries[index].title);

          }),
    );
```

Comment: Ohh...so it was simple logic which I could not think about..